Gatling check status saveAs function doesn't work with multiple status check
I am trying to check the HTTP status and save the status code in a variable, but in Gatling, if I add multiple status checks as follows.
.asJson().check(status().saveAs(RESPONSE_HTTP_STATUS_CODE), status().is(HttpStatus.SC_ACCEPTED)

saveAs function doesn't invoke and RESPONSE_HTTP_STATUS_CODE is always null.
What is the issue here?
Please refer to the following MVP to reproduce the issue.
https://github.com/eranga4u/demo-gatling
PS: I am not a Gatling expert.

This code is correct. There's no way to help you unless you provide a proper reproducer as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Please explain in the README the expected result and how it differs from the observed one.

@StéphaneLANDELLE I have added actual and expected results here: https://github.com/eranga4u/demo-gatling/tree/develop. Please have a look. I am looking forward to your reply. Thanks

The behavior you're observing is completely expected.
You're using exitHereIfFailed and exitBlockOnFail in several places in your scenario. When a request is failing, they cause the piece of code you're looking at to be bypassed.

It is working. Thanks for the help
